How to link segmentation views in Power BI
I am a newbie in Power BI desktop. I have a table with names of countries, regions and cities, and I want to create a segmentation so that the user can select only one state but is free to select the regions and cities (from that state) he wants.
Initially, I created a segmentation visual with the State column (set to single selection) and other segmentation visual with Region and City columns (set to multiple selection). It worked, but when I click on a city the other states disappear, forcing the user to first "unclick" the region/city to can change the state.
Example of segmentation with an incomplete Country filter
To solve this problem, I created a second table ("Countries"), only with the Country column, associated this column with the Country column of the first table ("Cities") and changed the first visual, setting Field to the Country column from the "Countries" table. This worked, but when I click on a country other than the one currently selected, the region and city subselections remains visible.
Example of segmentation with the previous selection of region and city still visible
So, I want to know how can I create some link or subordination between the views so that whenever a new country is selected, the selection of regions and cities "turns off" and shows only the regions and cities from that country.
